# Map AngularJS restAPI request via URL

Tags: angularjs, web-services, mapping, url-routing

Being new to angular I'm stocked to figure out how to call a web service which should be parsed and maped via URL, like if the URL is getting called directly to get listed request with the given params

what I mean let say I have

```
/api/products                            -- calling all products(this is the access point)
/api/products/?page=2&orderby=asc        -- calls products with pagination and orderby and here is what's bothering me because the api is getting called via ajax and there is no URL mapping of the target
```

My Codes

**Html markup**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">    
                    <pagination total-items="totalItems" num-pages="totalPages" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="selectPage(currentPage)" max-size="5" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true"></pagination>
                </div>
             <div ng-repeat="product in products"></div>
             </div>
 </div>
```

**contoller**

```
     //called when navigate to another page in the pagination
        $scope.selectPage = function(page) {
            $scope.filterCriteria.pageNumber = page;
            $scope.fetchResult();
        };


      //The function that is responsible of fetching the result from the server and setting the grid to the new result
        $scope.fetchResult = function() {               
            return api.items.search($scope.filterCriteria).then(function(data) {                    
                $scope.products = data;
                $scope.totalPages = data.total;
                $scope.productsCount = data.TotalItems;

            }, function() {
                $scope.products = [];
                $scope.totalPages = 0;
                $scope.productsCount = 0;
            });
        };
```

**Service**

```
.factory('api', function(Restangular) {
    //api call to 
    return {
        products: function() {
            return  Restangular.all('products').getList();

        },
        product: function(id) {
            Restangular.one("products", id ).get().then(function(c) {
                return c;
            });

        },

        update: function(id) {
            Restangular.one("products", id).put().then(function(c) {
                return c;
            });
        },
        items: {
            search: function(query) {
                return Restangular.all('products').getList(query);
            }
        },
    };
});
```

How do I create params URL and function of this make restAPI calls or what are the workarounds in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get at the search parameters with the `$location` service. So if a user goes to `somedomain.com/products/?page=2&orderby=asc` then `$location.search()` will equal `{page: 2, orderby: 'asc'}`.

So when your controller loads you just need to set the `filterCriteria` and fetch the results.

**controller**

```
var myCtrl = function($location, $scope) {
    $scope.selectPage = function(page) {
        ...
    };

    $scope.fetchResult = function() {               
        ...
    };

    $scope.filterCriteria = $location.search();
    $scope.fetchResults();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a restangular object by mentioning the base url. In your case it will be

```
// It will creat a url /api
var base = Restangular.all('api');
```

Now you can create multiple scenarios like if you want to get all products then it will be:

```
//  /api/products/
base.getList('products') 
.then(function(products) {
  $scope.products= products
})
```

Now if you want to apply pagination as well as include orderBy param

```
$scope.products = base.getList("products", [{page: 2},{orderby:asc}]);
```

Comment: my presented codes are working what I want: user gives in browser http://somedomain.com/products/?page=2&orderby=asc and than restangular defines a call to api like http://somedomain.com/products/?page=2&orderby=asc

Comment: That should be handled at the angular router level then. You using the default router provided by angular or angular-ui-router?